# Can I use Slax Linux while still storing data on my USB?

Tags: usb, dual-boot

I would like to install Slax, but I also want to keep my data.

In other words,
When I install Slax on my USB, can I still store data on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put Slax on a USB drive which has data as long as:

1. The drive is formatted with FAT[32] or a Linux filesystem (ex. ext4, BTRFS).
2. You leave the `/slax` directory at the root of the USB drive's filesystem alone; In other words, it's best not to put your data files in there.

In a nutshell, Slax is designed such that it boots from a single-partitioned device, such as what you'd get when you buy a formatted USB flash drive. See the [starting](https://www.slax.org/en/starting.php) and [internals](https://www.slax.org/en/internals.php) guides for more details.

Comment: So, don't put files in the USB, or don't put files in the Slax dir?

Comment: Don't put files in the Slax dir. In other words, you can create other directories (ex. /data) and put files there. That way you can't accidentally interfere with Slax.